# I created users in my project's app now how can i migrate them to actually django admin 'Users'?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Because of being a new comer in django i created the users in my app rather than in the actually django Users.Now how can i migrate my model to django admin Users so that i can let user login and out using inbuilt functions.
here is my admin page:

[Django Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvjeG.png)

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32,unique=True)
    emailid = models.EmailField(default='default@verify.com',unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    profilePic = models.FileField (default='/static/defaultPic/defaultPic.png/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username + ' ' + self.emailid + ' ' + self.password

class AccountInfo(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(Users,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField()
```

Comment: It depends on your own custom `User` model. But there's no silver bullet not magic wand here, you'll have to rewrite parts of your code and probably do some data migrations.

Comment: but i have to create my own authentication system for that :o

Comment: Nope, you have to fix your code (and possibly your data, unless you are not in production yet and can afford to dump your dev database) to make it compatible with django's custom User models, cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: Please post your `Userss` model.  You may have to reset the passwords, but apart from that you can migrate the users manually.

Comment: @2ps posted models.py in my question

Comment: It is likely you can use your custom user model directly. Try to add `AbstractBaseUser` as a parent class to your custom `User` class setting properties like `USERNAME_FIELD` and `REQUIRED_FIELDS` according, then run a migration. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: btw i forgot to tell you guys that i am not using a regular form instead its a bootstrap modal form which uses ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `AbstractBaseUser` class as mentioned by @PauloScardine or you can transfer your users’ information manually doing something like this:

```
from librarysystem.models import Users
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

for x in Users.objects.all():
    User.objects.create_user(x.username, x.email, x.password)
```

If you only have your data in your local machine, you can dump data using

```
python manage.py dumpdata librarysystem.Users --format=json --indent=2
```

And then create your users using the generated datafile.